# Booting directly into a test program

Tags: 16.04, boot, tty

I need to boot a computer several hundred times a day in order to do production-testing of computer peripherals.

I have an Ubuntu 16 test system where I ran `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target` to boot into text mode. I still have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> to launch the first tty. Then I have to log in, and then `sudo` my `test.sh` and enter a password again.

What I really wanted was to hit the power switch and see some pass / fail information and then shut back down.

The test script loads an appropriate driver, then runs a test program, so it needs superuser privileges.

I tried some getty stuff, but that failed miserably. I don't think the instructions were for Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Prerequisites

In order to boot to tty1 directly, remove `splash` from the following line in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

...and run `sudo update-grub`.

To prevent `systemd` from spawning a `getty` on tty1, mask the corresponding service:

```
sudo systemctl mask getty@tty1.service
```

### Create a systemd service unit

Create the following file, you can name it as you like of course:

**/etc/systemd/system/example.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Example tty1 service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/bin/bash /bin/example.sh
StandardOutput=tty
StandardInput=tty
TTYPath=/dev/tty1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

That service will be started after `multi-user.target` has been reached, run `/bin/example.sh` and use tty1 for input and output.

Run the following command to enable the service:

```
sudo systemctl enable example.service
```

I don't know what your script does, but here is an example that waits for a key press and shuts down the computer (you can still switch to another tty):

**/bin/example.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Press any key to shutdown
read -n 1 -s -r
poweroff
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

As root, create an executable file /etc/rc.local. In it, you can put any commands, shell scripts, etc. I'm assuming the things you re doing are non-interactive. If so, be sure to redirect output and errors to appropriate files. The rc.local file should have an "exit 0" at the end. Put your commands between the first line and last line.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

exit 0
```